# Insert or Update, and Update only if given timestamp is newer

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to

- Insert a new row into my table if it does not exist
- If key already exits, then update the entries but only if the field timestamp date is newer then the stored filed. I tried this with sqlite but it gives me an error near where. Im also not sure if this is correct and how to do it properly.

code:

```
String sql = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO "+TABLE_USER+" (...)" +
     " VALUES ('"..."'" + 
     ") WHERE " + timestamp + 
         " > (select " + COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + 
         " from " + TABLE_USER + " where " + COL_NUMBER + " = '" nr + "')"
```

Comment: i'd do that in 2 steps, which allows you to use the insert and update methods, which are much better than raw queries

Comment: (plus, there is no where clause in insert or replace, as plainly stated by the _documentation_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert or replace does not allow a where clause. I guess you have to do it in two steps.

Comment: how would you do this in 2 steps?

Comment: first check if the record exists and then do an insert or an update.

Answer (score 0):

Example of updating only if updated_at field is newer.

```
-- https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7jyj4n76MZHLLk2yszB6XD/22
 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db;

CREATE TABLE db
(
 id PRIMARY KEY,
 updated_at,
 other
);

INSERT INTO db (id,updated_at,other) VALUES(1,1,1);

SELECT * FROM db;

INSERT INTO db (id,updated_at,other) VALUES(1,2,2)
ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET updated_at=excluded.updated_at;

SELECT * FROM db;

-- WHERE is FALSE
INSERT INTO db (id,updated_at,other) VALUES(1,2,3)
ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET updated_at=excluded.updated_at, other=excluded.other
WHERE excluded.updated_at > updated_at;

SELECT * FROM db;

-- ok to SET a PRIMARY KEY. WHERE is TRUE
INSERT INTO db (id,updated_at,other) VALUES(1,3,4)
ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET id=excluded.id, updated_at=excluded.updated_at, other=excluded.other
WHERE excluded.updated_at > updated_at;

SELECT * FROM db;
```